# Spring Boot project using a spring data jpa project to retrieve users

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Data JPA project to access my Database and retrieve users credentials. I packaged this project as a jar (not an executable jar) and included it as a maven dependency to another Spring boot project because I wanted to reuse the same entities and repositories previously developed. every time I run my Spring Boot Application I get this error:

```
Action: If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

I am starting to wonder if what I am doing is even possible?
PS: I don't want to mix the JPA project with the controllers and services project

Comment: I think you are missing DB JAR on your classpath.

Comment: I have                                                                                                                                             
  `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1212.jre7</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: In spring boot application?

Comment: yes in I have it in both

Comment: have you added 'spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver' driver class name?

Comment: yes I do I have all the Data Source configuration and entity annotations... in place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145960/discussion-between-hrdkisback-and-chayma-atallah).

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I got the same error, I fix it adding this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

to the boot class, for example:

```
package com.adapter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DBAdapterApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DBAdapterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```